# How can I connect 2 dell monitors with Mac Air?

Tags: mac, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I am using MacBook Air(13-inch, 2017) model. I want to connect with 2 monitors Dell [(24 Monitor: E2420H)](https://www.dell.com/ae/p/dell-e2420h-monitor/pd)

The problem is the monitor doesn't have a HDMI port . It has only display port & VGA .

When I searched in the internet to find the adapter , I couldn't find any adapter that can support 2 display ports

Please suggest the best way to connect

Comment: Apple's Tech Specs page for the MacBook Air (https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) state it supports the internal display + one external display. At the same time, numerous posts on the internet suggest it supports 2 Thunderbolt-Displays when daisy-chained. Perhaps if you find the right dock (or combination of adapters) this can be accomplished, but as a lot of Thunderbolt 2 accessories are discontinued this might prove difficult. There are also options to connect displays over regular USB (Displaylink: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That model of laptop does not support connecting two external displays.  What is an option is adding an external GPU to enable more displays.  Here's an example, not a product suggestion and I'm not sure your laptop is supported: https://www.sonnetstore.com/products/egpu-breakaway-puck-5500xt

Again, that's an example of the kinds of products to look for, not a suggestion to buy.  I include that example as it gives some idea on what is available and how much they will cost.

In case of a dead link I'll describe the product as a Thunderbolt device containing a popular GPU, the same kind of GPU one would find on popular PCIe video cards, and on the device will be two or three video output ports.  Such boxes vary widely in price based on their capability, expect to pay at least $500 on the low end and there doesn't seem to be a ceiling on the price.  As these devices are using popular GPUs, just in a different form factor, they are widely supported by software published today.  Just double check that your laptop and the Thunderbolt GPU are compatible.

An option that often comes in at lower cost, but with lesser performance, are external GPUs that use USB instead of Thunderbolt.  They both use USB-C cables to connect but Thunderbolt GPUs are inherently more powerful than USB GPUs, and this is for reasons that get complicated quickly so I'll not go down that rabbit hole here.  These will run on the $200 and up price range.  Because they use USB GPUs and not Thunderbolt/PCIe GPUs they are not as well supported by software.  That's not saying they won't work, it's that they might not work as well.  The screen might not update as quickly, or you might not get as high of resolution on the screen.  As above double check for compatibility before purchase.

One thing to keep in mind, given the price of these external GPUs and the age of your current computer it may be more cost effective to simply buy a new laptop.  A new MacBook Pro would cost as much as some of these eGPUs, so perhaps a new laptop is in your future.